# where to save my ssh key file

Tags: ssh, users

I know that for any user I have to save the ssh key file into:

```
/home/any_user/.ssh/
```

But I do not know where to save the ssh key for the sudo.

Is it under `/root/.ssh` ?

Answer (score 2):

If by "the sudo" you mean the root user, then yes, that's exactly the location to store it.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to save the ssh key file into: `/home/any_user/.ssh/`

It is not true. You can store your key wherever you want, but it must be:

- secure place, so nobody else can read it
- if it is not standard location (`~/.ssh/id_{rsa,dsa,ecdsa,...}`, you need to tell `ssh` about the key. This is what we have config for. You can add line `IdentityFile path/to/your/key` into your `~/.ssh/config` to make it happen.

And yes, root has `~` (home directory) in `/root/` so the answer to your question is **Yes**.